# Windows Phone Binding Images

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone

Is it possible to bind a collection of images AND change their Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties? I know how to bind them to a ListBox, however, I wish to change their location and have the images scattered about.

The following code sends the data to a ListBox and renders the images one after the other in a list effect - of course.

I am unable to use Canvas.Left/Top properties as obviously the images are in a List Box.

**XML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxItems">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Stretch="None" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Room.Items.ImageUri}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
_roomView = new RoomViewModel();
            _roomView.Room = new Room
            {
                Items = new List<Item> {
                new Item {ImageUri = "/Escape;component/Images/Items/a.jpg"},
                new Item {ImageUri = "/Escape;component/Images/Items/b.png"},
                new Item {ImageUri = "/Escape;component/Images/Items/b.png"}}
            };

            listBoxItems.ItemsSource = _roomView.Room.Items;
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use in the **ItemTemplate**  **Canvas** insteed of the **StackPanel** you can use the **AttachedProperty: Canvas.Top/Canvas.Left** on the Image and on the TextBlock too. With that you can set the positions of the items as you wish. I hope it could help you.

Comment: Hi Ferenc. Could you kindly show me an example of this in XML please? I'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: Of course:
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxItems">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Margin="5">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Stretch="None" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Room.Items.ImageUri}"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="30"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

Comment: Thank you Ferenc. I'll have a look at it when I get home!

Comment: Could you check it? Was it what you looked for?